# How to debug a recursive function in unity C#

Tags: c#, debugging, unity-game-engine, recursion

Im trying to make a maze generator using recursion. Its not working how its supposed to work, and Im trying to figure out where the error is. So I want to step through the recursion 1 iteration at the time. How do I do this?

```
private void DevideRecursive(int pMinX, int pMaxX, int pMinY, int pMaxY)
{
    int randomX = Random.Range(pMinX +1, pMaxX);
    int randomY = Random.Range(pMinY +1, pMaxY);
    int randomWall = Random.Range(0, 4);

    List<GameObject> WalllistX1 = new List<GameObject>();
    List<GameObject> WalllistX2 = new List<GameObject>();
    List<GameObject> WalllistY1 = new List<GameObject>();
    List<GameObject> WalllistY2 = new List<GameObject>();
    List<List<GameObject>> MainWallList = new List<List<GameObject>>();

    MainWallList.Add(WalllistX1);
    MainWallList.Add(WalllistX2);
    MainWallList.Add(WalllistY1);
    MainWallList.Add(WalllistY2);

    //// add a wall on a random x coordinate
    for (int x = pMinX; x < pMaxX; x++)
    {
        GameObject wall = Instantiate(WallHor);
        wall.transform.position = new Vector2(tilesize * x + tilesize / 2, tilesize * randomY);
        if (x < randomX)
        {
            WalllistX1.Add(wall);
        }
        else
        {
            WalllistX2.Add(wall);
        }
    }
    //// add a wall on a random y coordinate
    for (int y = pMinY; y < pMaxY ; y++)
    {
        GameObject wall = Instantiate(WallVer);
        wall.transform.position = new Vector2(tilesize * randomX, tilesize * y + tilesize / 2);
        if (y < randomY)
        {
            WalllistY1.Add(wall);
        }
        else
        {
            WalllistY2.Add(wall);
        }
    }

    //make a hole in 3 out of tht 4 walls randomly
    for (int i = 0; i < MainWallList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (randomWall != i)
        {
            RemoveWall(MainWallList[i]);
        }
    }

    ////
    ////
    //// If either of the walls have a cell with only 1 grid stop the recursion


    Debug.Log("randomX - pMinX:" + (randomX - pMinX));
    Debug.Log("pMaxY - randomY:" + (pMaxY - randomY));
    Debug.Log("pMaxX - randomX:" + (pMaxX - randomX));
    Debug.Log("randomY - pMinY:" + (randomY - pMinY));

    if (!(randomX - pMinX <= 1) || !(pMaxY - randomY <= 1))
    {
        Debug.Log("a");
        DevideRecursive(pMinX, randomX, randomY, pMaxY);
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }

    if (!(pMaxX - randomX <= 1) || !(pMaxY - randomY <= 1))
    {
        Debug.Log("b");
        DevideRecursive(randomX, pMaxX, randomY, pMaxY);
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }

    if (!(randomX - pMinX <= 1 )|| !(randomY - pMinY <= 1))
    {
        Debug.Log("c");
        DevideRecursive(pMinX, randomX, pMinY, randomY);
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }

    if (!(pMaxX - randomX <= 1) || !(randomY - pMinY <= 1))
    {
        Debug.Log("d");
        DevideRecursive(randomX, pMaxX, pMinY, randomY);
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

This is my Recursive method. It get called in the Start function.
The method creates 2 random walls(1 vertical, 1 horizontal). Which devides the room in 4 smaller rooms. Then it does the same thing for those rooms.

Any help is appriciated

Comment: Add debug statements.. Or step through it in visual studio.

Comment: Could you explain? Ive tried using breakpoints but that doesnt work

Comment: did you attach visual studio to unity?

Comment: yes I have. ideally I want it so that when I press a button it will go trough the next iteration

Comment: but you can do that, if the first line of recursion is a break, resume and it will break again next loop..

Comment: Ive tried that but I cant resume it for some reason. Im not sure if its a bug or if im doing something wrong

Comment: Well without an explaination of what even happens when you try, its like shooting in the dark with a blind fold on and ear plugs

Answer (score -1):

You could modify the function to use `async`.

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
void Start () {
    DevideRecursive( ..params.. );
}
private async void DevideRecursive(int pMinX, int pMaxX, int pMinY, int pMaxY) {
    // code
    while (!Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        await Task.Yield ();
    // code
    DevideRecursive( .. params .. );
    return
}
```

More infomation on aysnc in Unity [here](http://www.stevevermeulen.com/index.php/2017/09/using-async-await-in-unity3d-2017/).
An IEnumerator could also be used, which gives you the option to control the function externally.

Comment: I get an error at this saying: "the await operator can only be used in a aysnc method". Which makes sense. Are you sure that it can be used like that?

void Start () {
    await DevideRecursive(0, Rows, 0, Columns);
}




as my method

Comment: try `async void Start () {`

Comment: gives "cannot await "void" ". I have never really worked with awaits before. But if this works. How am I supposed to get to the next iteration with for example a key press?

Comment: Sorry, you don't put `await` to start the async method, only to wait for it. I also changed to code to iterate on keypress

Comment: Downvoted for bringing `async`/`await` into this. Why in the world would you bring `async`/`await` into this...?